# handshake_failure trying to access file on same server

Tags: ssl

My code is trying to access a template file on the same server as the application.
It all worked fine until we switched on SSL.

Now when connecting to the file I get a SSLHandshakeException: handshake_failure with not much information on the actual cause of the issue.
If I try to access the file through the browser I get a warning page asking if I want to proceed at my own risk.

Is it a problem with the certificate? Can I bypass it?

Edit: The server is JBoss EAP 6.1 with Java 1.7. It's configured to use TLS1.2.
The bit retrieving the template is:

```
URL url;
URLConnection urlConnection;
try {
  url = new URL(templateUrl);
  urlConnection = url.openConnection();

  urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(connectionTimeout);
  urlConnection.setReadTimeout(connectionTimeout);
  BufferedReader breader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

  String line;
  while ((line = breader.readLine()) != null) {
    strHtmlContent.append(line);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Handshake error is usually not a problem with the certificate, at least not with the validation of the certificate. It can have several other reasons, typically wrong protocol version, no cipher overlap, missing use of SNI... .

Unfortunately it is impossible to say what the problem is in your specific case but you might narrow it down by trying to access the site with different clients (i.e. browser, curl, ...). If not even a browser can access the site it is probably a misconfiguration of the server.

Comment: As I said in the question I can access the specific URL via browser, just I get the warning page that the certificate is not valid and I can proceed at my own risk. I get the warning only once. After I "accept the risk" then all subsequent times I just get the file. What seems strange is that the application trying to access the file and the file itself are on the same server.

Comment: @algiogia: it does usually does not matter if this is the same system or not. You will probably get the certificate validation error with your (unkown) application too once you resolved the handshake error. One might help to find the reason for the handshake failure if you provide more details to your application, especially how the application uses TLS, which TLS stack, which version etc.